# parsing python to csv

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I'm trying to download some game stats to do some analysis, only problem is each season the data their isn't 100% consistent.

I grab the json file from the site, then wish to save it to a csv with the first line in the csv containing the heading for that column, so the heading would be essentially the key from the python data type.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json
import csv

base_url = 'http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/'

token_url = base_url + 'WMCTok'
player_url = base_url + 'matchItems/round'


def printPretty(data):
    print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))

session = requests.Session() # session makes it simple to use the token across the requests
token = session.post(token_url).json()['token'] # get the token
session.headers.update({'X-media-mis-token': token}) # set the token

Season = 2014
Roundno = 4

if Roundno<10:
    strRoundno = '0'+str(Roundno)
else:
    strRoundno = str(Roundno)


# get some data (could easily be a for loop, might want to put in a delay using Sleep so that you don't get IP blocked)
data = session.get(player_url + '/CD_R'+str(Season)+'014'+strRoundno)


# print everything
printPretty(data.json())

with open('stats_game_test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter="'",quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)


    for profile in data.json()['items']:
                spamwriter.writerow(['%s' %(profile)])


#for key in data.json().keys():
#   print("key: %s , value: %s" % (key, data.json()[key]))
```

The above code grabs the json and writes it to a csv, but it puts the key in each individual cell next to the value (eg  'venueId': 'CD_V190'), the key needs to be just across the first row as a heading.

It gives me a csv file with data in the cells like this

```
Column A                          B
'tempInCelsius': 17.0     'totalScore': 32
'tempInCelsius': 16.0     'totalScore': 28
```

What I want is the data like this

```
tempInCelsius           totalScore
    17                        32
    16                        28
```

As I mentioned up the top, the data isn't always consistent so if I define what fields to grab with spamwriter.writerow([profile['tempInCelsius'], profile['totalScore']]) then it will error out on certain data grabs.

This is why I'm now trying the above method so it just grabs everything regardless of what data is there.

Comment: Can you clearly report what you got from the program and what you need?

Comment: Show the source JSON

Answer (score 0):

you want to write a heading first

spamwriter.writerow('tempInCelsius', 'totalScore') # if you assume the column names else get them by key or what have you

and then for loop write the values

spamwriter.writerow([profile['tempInCelsius'], profile['totalScore']])

Comment: This is what I have also done, but the problem with this is that for instance in 2010 there was no tempInCelsius recorded, so if I loop through the years it will error out and all the data is now out of alignment with the headings. It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: wel, in this case you can iterate once over your full data and collect all keys from it, and then write the header row followed by some if key in data: write to file